# Car not starting

Tags: starting, ignition

My car worked fine till yesterday and yesterday evening I just injected engine oil, power steering oil, coolant and water for wipers. I am pretty sure I added right fluids in right places and I parked my car after a few kilometers drive. The next day morning my car stopped working !!!

My car battery is good, A/C running, lights working and when I try to ignite, engine is trying to start but its not starting. The jushhh!!! sound while trying to start the car is as usual and even I tried giving a long shot but still car is not starting.

Just behaving like no fuel in tank. I even tried adding 10 lts of petrol and tried still the issue was not resolved.

Any idea what would be the issue behind this?

If the problem is with the oils, is there anyway to get confirmation that oils are responsible for the issue?

Comment: Model is Holder Commodore and I just filled the fluid levels without removing the existing fluids.

Comment: 1998 Commodore Mark

Answer (score 3):

From the data you have given it could be connected with you topping up the fluids incorrectly, but to be honest it could be anything- you could have even knocked a wire while you were working on the engine.

If you did put the wrong oil in the wrong place I would suggest based on your question that you take it to your local garage as if you haven't drained and replaced oils before it could be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the engine requires fuel and spark.  If you want to try and diagnose this yourself, you can see about renting a fuel pressure test gauge and hooking it up to the test port on your fuel rail under the hood.  You can pull the plug wires one at a time and hook up a spark tester to verify the plugs are getting juice from the ignition coil.  If you're short spark or fuel pressure, you've got a subsystem to investigate.  If they're both present, you're getting into engine management territory.  Is the check engine light on?